# Publishing views from Microsoft SQL Server in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, sql-server

I am developing the application with OpenLayers 3 and GeoServer for serving WMS layers. The Layers are published from Microsoft SQL Server in GeoServer.

In MSSQL server, there are two databases, First database consists of all the spatial and non spatial tables and views which used by some other web application to view and edit the attribute data of each spatial assets.

The second database can contain some spatial tables (layers) which can be directly published from GeoServer, but there are some views which has created from the first database. So that if there is any updating for assets has been done in the that web application it will affect the attributes of views in the second database.

I am using the second database for my application. I can easily publish the tables which has uploaded directly from shapefile to MSSQL Server. The problem is while publishing the views in GeoServer, it throws an exception.

[image: GeoServer Exception]

Exception from GeoServer log

> 2015-10-15 16:49:05,699 ERROR [wicket.RequestCycle] - java.io.IOException: Error occured calculating bounds for spatial_view
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Error occured calculating bounds for spatial_view
>       at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getBoundsInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:540)
>       at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getBounds(ContentFeatureSource.java:428)
>       at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getBounds(ContentFeatureSource.java:364)
>       at org.vfny.geoserver.global.GeoServerFeatureSource.getBounds(GeoServerFeatureSource.java:660)
>       at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.getNativeBounds(CatalogBuilder.java:561)
>       at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.getNativeBounds(CatalogBuilder.java:543)
>       at org.geoserver.web.data.resource.BasicResourceConfig$2.onClick(BasicResourceConfig.java:155)
>       at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerAjaxFormLink.onSubmit(GeoServerAjaxFormLink.java:44)
>       at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxSubmitLink$1.onSubmit(AjaxSubmitLink.java:68)
>       at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:143)
>       at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:177)
>       at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:300)
>       at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.listener.BehaviorRequestTarget.processEvents(BehaviorRequestTarget.java:119)
>       at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
>       at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
>       at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
>       at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436)
>       at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
>       at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:484)
>       at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doPost(WicketServlet.java:160)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:159)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
>       at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
>       at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:83)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error occured calculating bounds for spatial_view
>       at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.getBounds(JDBCDataStore.java:1309)
>       at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getBoundsInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:533)
>       ... 115 more
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot resolve collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in add operator occurring in SELECT statement column 1.
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:792)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:689)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerStatement.java:616)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
>       at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.getBounds(JDBCDataStore.java:1285)
>       ... 116 more
>   2015-10-15 16:49:05,708 INFO [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "POST /geoserver/web/?wicket:interface=:8:resource:tabs:panel:theList:0:content:referencingForm:computeLatLon::IActivePageBehaviorListener:0:&wicket:ignoreIfNotActive=true&random=0.15636781346984208" took 33ms
>   2015-10-15 16:49:05,714 INFO [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/web/?wicket:interface=:9::::" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/?wicket:interface=:8::::" " "" 
>   2015-10-15 16:49:05,734 INFO [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/web/?wicket:interface=:9::::" took 20ms

The *geometry_columns* table in second database (which I am using) has stored the geometry column name as **ogr_geometry** but views has the geometry column name as **SP_GEOMETRY**...

Is this the problem, if so how to over come it?

or how to publish this MSSQL Server views using GeoServer 2.7.2?

Comment: You should share the entire stack trace, it can be found in the logs (geoserver.log in the data directory)

Comment: Just want to check that you have the MS SQL Server extension installed: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlserver.html

Comment: Yes I have installed extension and I have published the spatial tables. But problem arises while publishing spatial views

Answer (score 2):

I confirm this issue.

As a workaround I suggest creating layer with SRS bounds, not ones that calculated from data. (Error comes from bbox query on data).

Answer (score 1):

From your stack trace it seems you have some issues with text fields in your views: "Cannot resolve collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"